# How to set horizontal scroll pane starting location on the left end?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

My code for JScrollPane are as follow :-

```
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane (textArea,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

The issue I have is that when i run the program the scroll bar always starts from the right end which is the ending of the sentence.

[image]

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. So all you need is a JFrame with a JTextArea added to a JScrollpane and some text added to the text area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sasikumar's answer is correct. It just needs a small adaption in order to be sure that the `JScrollBar` will get its value changed. Try to call it like that:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    JScrollBar horizontalScrollBar = sp.getHorizontalScrollBar();
    horizontalScrollBar.setValue(horizontalScrollBar.getMinimum());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Initial start with like this

```
JScrollBar horScrBar = sp.getHorizontalScrollBar();
horScrBar.setValue(horScrBar.getMinimum());
```